# Covariant derivative is orthogonal projection

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm studying some Riemannian geometry and am having difficulty understanding some calculations and notions with the covariant derivative. In particular I am currently stuck on the following:

Let $S^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be the usual unit sphere with the induced Riemannian metric from the Euclidean metric of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. If $\gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow S^n$ a curve and $V(t)$ a vector field on $S^n$ along the curve $\gamma$, that is, $V(t) \in T_{\gamma(t)} S^n$ for all $t \in [a,b]$, show the covariant derivative (defined using the Levi-Civita connection on $S^n$ is given by:
$$
\frac{DV}{dt} = \text{pr}_{T_{\gamma(t)}S^n}(V'(t))
$$
where pr denotes orthogonal projection and $V'(t)$ is the usual derivative in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Bonus: generalise this to arbitrary submanifold $N$ of a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with the induced metric on $N$.

My idea was to expand the covariant derivative as follows:
$$
\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}} V = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{dV_i}{dt} + \sum_{j,k=1}^{n} \Gamma_{jk}^{i} \frac{d\gamma_j}{dt} V_k(t)\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
$$
and then hope to simplify this via calculating the Christoffel symbols or something of the kind but I'm having some trouble from here.

Comment: How are you using the fact that your Levi-Civita connection is on $S^n$?

Comment: It would probably be easier here to go the other way and start with the flat LC connection on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. If we define the "induced connection" $\hat{\nabla}$ on a submanifold by
$$
\hat{\nabla}_U(V)=\text{pr}(\nabla_{\tilde{U}}\tilde{V})
$$
Where $\tilde{U},\tilde{V}$ are arbitrary extensions of $U,V$, then it's just a matter of showing that the formula is independent of the choice of extensions and that $\hat{\nabla}$ is also a LC connection (which is unique).